How can I create a left-aligned table of a fixed width containing equations?
My goal is to create a two column table with fixed column widths where each row contains two individually numbered left aligned equations.
However, when putting equations inside a table with the W or w column type
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% with m instead of W{l} this compiles without errors
\begin{tabular}{W{l}{4cm} W{l}{4cm}}
    \begin{equation} 1 + 1 = 2 \end{equation}
            & \begin{equation} 1 - 1 = 0 \end{equation}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

LaTeX complains about

Missing $ inserted.

and

You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.

How can I get a table of left-aligned equations where the columns have a fixed width? Why is my approach not working - especially as the document compiles fine with m as column type?

Welcome to TeX.SE. What's your reason for not wishing to employ the m (or p) column type?

And why numbered equations inside a table? This gets annoying for readers

you could use $x=y$ but equations (in a table?) are display enviornments so need to be in a parbox, so p{...} not l

I need to left-align the equation, how can I do this in a m or p column?
The format is a requirement I have to adhere to.

Would you please add a sketch of the expected result?

Like this:

(red lines indicate page layout).
It is not clear, if left align of equations should be in the whole document or just in table. In MWE below I consider the last case. By help of nccmath package you can write:
\documentclass{report}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{fleqn}% for left aligning of equations
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}  p{4cm} }
    \begin{equation} 1 + 1 = 2 \end{equation}
            & \begin{equation} 1 - 1 = 0 \end{equation}
\end{tabular}
\end{fleqn}

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}

